# Android Clock App Set Alarm

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms

I need to know if this is possible, and if it is, how I should proceed.

I'd like to make an app that will create a repeating alarm within the stock Android Clock App. It should go off at 8am each morning and should only take one button to activate within my app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: all you need is here https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: @zombie that will create an alarm in the clock app?

Comment: no it will be an alarm in your app but I'm not sure if you can add something in the default alarm app. that would be managing a different app's data

Comment: you might be able to send an action to the default alarm by deep link URL and i will be the job of the alarm to handle to request

Comment: @zombie yes this is more along the lines of what I am trying to do, any idea on how to do this? Thanks for your help by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void createAlarm(String message, int hour, int minutes) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

Comment: Thanks friend, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

> I found this way for Clock

```
public void createAlarm(String message, int hour, int minutes) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)// show on it
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour) //24 hours
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes); //not more than 60 :)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```